# Транслитерация в input поле

Tags: jquery

Как сделать, чтоб при вводе в это поле русских символов проходила транслитерация, и пробелы менялись символом "-"?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control width-500" name="xfield[artist]" id="xf_artist" value="Қайрат Нұртас &amp; Заңғар Нұртас">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.value = textTransform(this.value);
});

function textTransform(text){
  var arrru = [ 'Я','я','Ю','ю','Ч','ч','Ш','ш','Щ','щ','Ж','ж','А','а','Б','б','В','в','Г','г','Д','д','Е','е','Ё','ё','З','з','И','и','Й','й','К','к','Л','л','М','м','Н','н', 'О','о','П','п','Р','р','С','с','Т','т','У','у','Ф','ф','Х','х','Ц','ц','Ы','ы','Ь','ь','Ъ','ъ','Э','э', ' ' ];
  var arren = [ 'Ya','ya','Yu','yu','Ch','ch','Sh','sh','Sh','sh','Zh','zh','A','a','B','b','V','v','G','g','D','d','E','e','E','e','Z','z','I','i','J','j','K','k','L','l','M','m','N','n', 'O','o','P','p','R','r','S','s','T','t','U','u','F','f','H','h','C','c','Y','y','`','`','\'','\'','E', 'e', '-' ];

  for(var i=0; i<arrru.length; i++){
    var reg = new RegExp(arrru[i], "g");
    text = text.replace(reg, arren[i]);
  }
  
  return text;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Comment: Отлично, а можно, чтоб еще дублировалось в другое поле?

Comment: @razmenyairu, какое "другое"? Другого поля вроде в задаче не значится.

Comment: @MedvedevDev [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833044/%d0%a2%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-input-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5#comment1332260_833108)

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот такой код валялся:

```js
    var input = document.getElementById('input');

    input.addEventListener('input', function() {
      this.value = textTransform(this.value);
    });

    var tr = {"а":"a","б":"b","в":"v","ґ":"g","г":"g","д":"d","е":"e","ё":"e","є":"ye","ж":"zh","з":"z","и":"i","і":"i","ї":"yi","й":"i","к":"k","л":"l","м":"m","н":"n","о":"o","п":"p","р":"r","с":"s","т":"t","у":"u","ф":"f","x":"h","ц":"c","ч":"ch","ш":"sh","щ":"sh'","ъ":"","ы":"i","ь":"","э":"e","ю":"yu","я":"ya"};
     
    var spaceReplacement = '-';


    function textTransform(str){
      if (str === null || str === undefined || str === "") {
        return "";
      }
      var new_str = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                    var strLowerCase = str[i].toLowerCase();
                    if (strLowerCase === " ") {
                        new_str += spaceReplacement;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (!tr[strLowerCase]) {
                        new_str += strLowerCase;
                    } else {
                        new_str += tr[strLowerCase];
                    }
       }
       return new_str;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Comment: Отлично, а можно, чтоб еще дублировалось в другое поле?

Comment: @razmenyairu что ты подразумеваешь под "продублировать" и "другое поле"?

Comment: Ну когда пишешь в поле <input type="text" id="input">. вставлялось еще что я написал в поле <input type="text" id="input1">

Comment: сделай это самостоятельно - нужно добавить в `input.addEventListener` копирование данных во второе поле

Comment: Помоги пожалуйста, у меня не выходит(

Comment: Сделал, можно чуточку переделать скрипт, и сделать,  чтоб при вводе в поле <input type="text" id="input"> текста, дубликал шел в <input type="text" id="input1">, но с транслитом. А в <input type="text" id="input"> оставался как есть?

Answer (score -1):

все довольно просто:

```
$( "#xf_artist" ).change(function() {
  var valchng = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(valchng.replace(" ", "-"));
});
```

можно сократить и уместить все в одной строке внутри функции, специально оставил так для наглядности.

upd: спасибо Игорь, описался с this, поправил.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.val is not a function

Comment: `$(this).val()`